# Why am I unable to answer a protected question with 101 rep?

Tags: support, answers, reputation, privileges

I have more than 10 rep, but I am unable to answer [Nvidia driver activated but currently not in use](https://askubuntu.com/q/37084/88802), which is "protected":

> protected by Community♦ May 23 '11 at 1:32
>
> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site.

I struggled with the issue for months and I finally figured it out today, but none of those answers were my problem.

I have never posted on Ask Ubuntu before but I have over 6500 rep on Stack Overflow and my reputation lists me as having the 100 site transfer bonus.

What's wrong?

Comment: Which post were you trying to answer?

Comment: @Seth I linked it with []() syntax in my OP http://askubuntu.com/questions/37084/nvidia-driver-activated-but-currently-not-in-use

Comment: Ah, I thought that was your own question. Misread that sentence there.

Answer (score 8):

You need more than 10 rep on this (Ask Ubuntu) specific site. The association bonus sadly don't count towards this hence you need to get 10 hard earned rep here to do so.

Comment: Aha, association bonus doesn't count. That explains it, thanks

Comment: This is a UX fail, to have multiple flavors of reputation that aren't evident. If nothing else the message should state "posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site (and the association bonus doesn't count)." But really, if the site is going to grant 100 reputation for association bonus, it should be the same as other rep so there aren't mixed messages ("We trust you because you gave good answers elsewhere! Except we don't trust you quite yet.")

Comment: @joseph_morris If I'm not wrong, it's evident "To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation **on this site.**" (I protected this question so you can verify it)

Comment: Oddly, I do have a "Your Answer" box here despite the protection (I'm not answering since I don't have a better answer). So it only seems to pertain to the main askubuntu, not the meta. I do not think it is evident "on this site" does not include the association bonus (it says "You've earned a bonus of 100 reputation because we trust you on other sites in the network", and the only reputation number ever displayed in the site header, etc. includes association). See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481/improve-protected-question-message-with-regard-to-rep-gained-through-associati